# Where distinct ID has two values

Tags: mysql

I apologize for the weird title, I really can't think of a way to describe this. I'm just having a complete mental block. Basically, the table layout looks like so:

```
id, customer_id, company, date, (... other irrelevant fields)
1   1            CompanyA    02/08/1111
2   1            CompanyB    02/08/1111
3   1            CompanyC    02/08/1111
```

I basically want to select all the customer ID's that have records in that table for both `CompanyA` and `CompanyB`

How would I go about this?

Comment: `select * from tabName 
where 
company=CompanyA
AND
company=CompanyB`

Comment: @dhpratik `company` cannot have two values at the same time

Comment: SELECT customer_id FROM tabName WHERE company IN ('CompanyA','CompanyB');

Comment: `select * from tab1 as t1, tab1 as t2 where t1.company=CompanyA and t2.company=CompanyB`

this should work

Answer (score 5):

To return all `company_ids` that have both `CompanyA` and `CompanyB` then you should be able to use a GROUP BY with a HAVING clause to get the result:

```
select customer_id
from yourtable
where company in ('CompanyA', 'CompanyB')
group by customer_id
having count(distinct company) >= 2;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3057/1).

If you just want to return any `company_ids` with either `CompanyA` or `CompanyB` then you can use an `IN`:

```
select customer_id
from yourtable
where company in ('CompanyA', 'CompanyB')
```

Comment: I think the first query is not correct. If CompanyA appears twice for a customer_id, this query would return it

Comment: @Augusto No it won't that is why it is using `DISTINCT`. If I didn't include `DISTINCT` in the `HAVING` clause then you would be correct -- see a demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3265c/1

Comment: I'm blind. My apologies :).

Comment: @Augusto no worries! :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out just as I posted this. I've been writing complicated queries all day and I just couldn't get it. It literally is just an `OR` query.

Comment: OK, then you didn't word the question very well ;) @bluefeet's answer does what I *thought* you meant...

Comment: plz put the answer so we can also can know and use in case of future

Comment: @BenM I did, and I can only blame a long hard day of SQL :(